Error while performing py manage.py runserver in Django
While executing the Django project it displays the below error message:
py .\manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 14, in main
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Python version is 3.12.
Django version is 5
The path of Python is configured in the environment variables.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Django.
I also tried deleting my project and creating a new project, but it displays an error
py manage.py runserver    
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

From the file manage.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'InternshipDjango.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


How did you install Django? More specifically, did you use a virtual environment? And if you did, did you activate the virtual environment before running runserver?

@Vegard I installed it by executing "py -m pip install Django==5.0.6"
i did not use any virtual environments

Sure, but did you do so in a virtual environment?

@Vegard I didn't use any virtuals environment. Is it necessary to use one?

Not strictly speaking necessary, but it can often be a great help and convenience for a whole range of things (probably this particular issue included). venv is a sort of simple standard for Python virtual environments, should be pretty simple to get into if you want to try it out.

@Vegard after using virtual environment it works completely fine. Thank you.

Ensure your Django is actually installed in your python environment variable path.
Ensure Django is installed correctly, using code
pip show django

To check py environment variable, using code
import sys
print(sys.path)


pip show django command shows the django is installed correctly
after ececuting import sys  print(sys.path)
i am getting toomany paths :  ['c:\Python', 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs', 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39', 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
